# Trying to make php run in a post

Tags: php, posts

I'm trying to make this php code run in a post.
Using a plugin to enable the php to run.

Problem is I can't seem to get it to work no matter how I structure the statements :/

I'm sure it's something simple but I'm just not familiar enough with php yet to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
[insert_php]if(!get_post_meta(get_the_ID()),'buy_status', true);
echo "<h5 style="text-align: center;display: block;">";
echo "Sorry, this piece is sold.";
else
echo "<h5 style="text-align: center;display: none;">";
endif;[/insert_php]
</h5>
```

Comment: Hi James. Questions about third party plugins and themes are off-topic here on WPSE, so it would be best to ask in the forum provided by the developer of the plugiin. Side note, allowing PHP to run in a post is not a good practice. It would be better to create a [`[shortcode]`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Dave, the question is about how to structure the php statements. The problem is the same for me even in a shortcode. If you read the question, I'm not asking how to make a theme or plugin work :) I'm asking about structuring the php so it works. Please read the questions in context.

Comment: Okay, but [vanilla PHP questions are still off-topic here on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking). :-) I've added a solution which should act as a decent starting point and it doesn't rely on needing to run PHP in the content area.

Comment: What is a vanilla question?? Are you saying this is not a place for newbies to ask or learn?.

Comment: Inserting PHP code into content is a recipe for disaster. Plugins that add a way to put PHP code in the admin area like this are security disasters, massive exploit holes just waiting to be used, and encourage a method of development that very quickly leads to massive problems ( e.g. you'll run into major problems the moment you try to do simple things with the WordPress APIs, such as calling get_post_meta, etc )

Comment: Alright, I get that Tom and appreciate the comment. I will use a short code. No worries there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a [`[shortcode]`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) which doesn't rely on running PHP inside of the content area. Here are the docs for [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) which show how that function should be called.

```
add_shortcode( 'buy_status', 'wpse249289_buy_status' );
function wpse249289_buy_status( $atts ) {
    $output = '';
    if ( ! get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'buy_status', true ) ) {
        // Post meta value for key buy_status is false
        $output .= '<h5 style="text-align: center;display: block;">';
        $output .= 'Sorry, this piece is sold.';
        $output .= '</h5>';
    } else {
        // Post meta value for key buy_status is not false
        $output .= '<h5 style="text-align: center;display: none;"></h5>'; // Not sure why you'd want to output anything
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dave! I did read the docs but did not see any reference to the !. In finding what hat meant, it apparently inverts the statement. Meaning it looks for false instead of true I suppose. Why do that?

Comment: You got it, James, and yes you are correct. `!` is the [*logical not operator*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Often times, code will be structured so that the false conditions are checked first before the true conditions. This code could easily be rewritten to be the other way around though.

Comment: Okay, just wondering. So tell me, I just read over the types of topics that can be queried here (again). I am missing why this question is not something to be asked here. It applies to Wordpress in that I am trying to understand how to make php dynamically write HTML into a post. I am not a php programmer. I write code. Sometimes I get it right, sometimes I don't. I came here to get help with understanding what I did wrong. Dave provided that and I very much appreciate it. So, is the question inappropriate or not?? We can only learn from those who already know.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is off topic, but it's on the border line. That's just my opinion though. `if(!get_post_meta(get_the_ID()),'buy_status', true);` should have produced a syntax error. The PHP in the content plugin might have been masking that. Don't sweat it though, just keep doing your thing. It's always great to help folks that wan't to learn. If this solution solved your issue, please click the check mark to close it out.

Comment: One last question regarding the value of the post_meta. I dynamically create the buy_status key and the value. Currently, it is created with a function when I receive an IPN from PayPal. I set the value to 1, meaning true. The key doesn't exist until a transaction triggers its creation. Should I set it to 0 for false? Will the shortcode function hiccup if no key is present at all?  Thanks :)

Comment: I will try it momentarily and check the box :)

Comment: get_post_meta() returns `false` when the `$single` argument is set to `true` (as in our example) and there is no meta key set. So you should be fine here -- no need to explicitly set `buy_status` to `0`;

Comment: Much appreciated Dave! Not only am I new at this, I'm a 58 year old geezer and an oil painter lol! Got those two things going against me becoming an eating, thinking, living, breathing, logical thinking coder :) But I do learn the stuff and want to. Thanks for bearing with me ;)

Comment: Very happy to help, James!